# lubridate::round_date () gives all zeros on a large data set

Tags: r, datetime, rounding, lubridate

I am trying to use lubridate::round_date () for a datetime column on a big data set (~3 milion rows * 23 columns) using this code:

```
time_bin <- "1 hour"    
data %<>% mutate(rounded_time = lubridate::round_date(UTC_datetime, time_bin),
                 time_format = strftime(rounded_time,format = "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S"))%>% droplevels()
```

When running this code on a subsampled data set (1000 rows):

```
data<-data[1:1000,]
```

everything works great and the time is rounded to the nearest hour:

```
head(data)[,25]
```

[1] "2019-10-01 04:00:00" "2019-10-01 05:00:00" "2019-10-01 06:00:00" "2019-10-01 07:00:00"
[5] "2019-10-01 09:00:00" "2019-10-01 10:00:00"

whereas when running the code over the full data set I get the date and all zeros where the time should be:

```
head(data)[,25]
```

> [1] "2019-10-01 00:00:00" "2019-10-01 00:00:00" "2019-10-01 00:00:00" "2019-10-01 00:00:00"
>   [5] "2019-10-01 00:00:00" "2019-10-01 00:00:00"

Any idea to what could have gone wrong and how to fix it?

Thanks!
Idan

Comment: What is the minimum number of rows that causes an error?

Comment: Somewhere between 45,000 and 46,000 rows

Comment: And if you start from the end, how many rows can you process? I guess I'm trying to help you determine if the problem is the function, or potentially some of your data.

Comment: when starting from the end I get the same error of all zeros. I researched the issue a little deeper and found the first row that causes the error and found that it does it even when I run the code only on that one row. However, when looking in the raw data, I do not find any difference between the row that causes the error and the previous one that works. The raw data is automatically recorded from GPS transmitters so no human errors are expected to be the problem... Any idea? TNX.

Comment: Can you `dput()` the faulty row?

Comment: I had a gps dataset that blew up my code because the lat and long were just outside feasible values for one observation out of roughly a million. Try dput () as per comment above.